# Pine Script / TradingView - Get Close Price of particular hour on Daily Chart?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm using a daily chart, and would like to get the close price of the ticker at a particular hour (let's say 15:00 EST), how do I go about doing that?

I know I can do:

```
TimePrice := (hour== 15 and minute == 0) ? close : TimePrice
```

But that only seems to work on charts that are half hour or faster.

Is there a way to get the close price for a particular hour while using the daily chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully tested but you can try this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Show close price at 15:00",overlay=true)

tnow  = timenow
t1500 = timestamp(year(time) , month(time) , dayofmonth(time) , 15 ,  0, 0) 
t1530 = timestamp(year(time) , month(time) , dayofmonth(time) , 15 , 30, 0) 
index = tnow>t1530? 2: tnow>t1500? 1 : na

close30 = index>=0 ? request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", close[index]) : na

a = array.new_float(1)
array.set(a, 0, close30)
close1500 = array.get(a, 0)[0]

var table msgDisplay = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 1)
table.cell(msgDisplay,  0,  0, str.tostring(close1500), bgcolor = color.yellow)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).